# How to transfer e.g. "12/31/2018" to "2018Q4" in excel?

Tags: excel, date

Can anyone help me transfer the "12/31/2018" to "2018Q4" in Excel?

Should be the exact format.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula

```
=YEAR(A1)&"Q"&CEILING(MONTH(A1)/3,1)
```

Comment: Thank you! the answer is perfect.